# How to run a batch file with different built-in credentials?

Tags: batch-file, runas

I want to put the following into a batch file so i can convert it to a .exe and allow another user to run it on another PC.

The user does not have local admin access and has a frequent problem with their com1 port. I have installed/copied devcon to the user's PC and have gotten this script working fine without the credential change, i just need to know how i can run the batch file as a local user.

This is what i have written:

```
runas.exe /profile /user:localpcname\administrator /password:12345678
Devcon disable "ACPI\PNP0501"
timeout /t 5
Devcon enable "ACPI\PNP0501"
```

"Runas" seems to always want to run something else instead of everything else in a batch file?

Comment: Are you using a third party application called "runas.exe"? runas doesn't have a `/password` option.

Comment: Also, `runas` takes a single command to execute - it doesn't elevate the current executing context. So you should have 2 batch scripts - the first will just contain the `runas` command, executing batch script 2 which contains your real logic.

Comment: Presumably you are aware of the obvious security problem of having an administrator password in plain text in a batch file? I mean - you might as well just grant the user local admin access at that point, and cut out the middle-man!

Comment: @RB OP intended to convert the script into an .exe (which is still insecure because it just wraps the script and extracts/calls it in plain text upon execution). Though it is possible to use multiple commands with `runas`. The correct syntax for the command in question would be: `runas /user:localpcname\administrator "cmd /c Devcon disable "ACPI\PNP0501"&timeout 5&Devcon enable "ACPI\PNP0501""`.

Answer (score 0):

G'day Regejok, thank you very much that works perfectly. Yes i am aware of the security implications of an open text password in a batch file, and i am aware i could make the user a local administrator. However doing that would be a lot more difficult than this solution (GPO's manage local users and they are kept overseas) and i don't want to confuse the user(s) any more than i need to.

Add in the fact that the equipment attached to this one PC is flakey at the best of times has led me here.

I really like the fact that i can run additional commands within the same batch file by using the /c switch. I don't know much at all about scripting so this is a great help :)

It looks like the ampersands are used in a similar was as brackets are when writing/typing too: devcon do-this "blah"(and then do this)Devcon do-that "blah again"

I understand.